# Octave- How to find active object in axis

Tags: user-interface, graphics, line, handle, octave

Matlab has a property called gco (get current object) that can be used to identify a line after mouse press.

For example:
waitforbuttonpress
handle=gco
.. do something with handle...

Octave has gcf (get current figure) and gca (get current axes), but does it have a similar mechanism than Matlab's gco. Target is to manipulate lines in the axis and they are identified with mouse clicks.

BR, Antti

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are asking, but I know one possible workaround which at the very least could be expanded to fulfill what you are looking for. If you do:

```
 n = 3;
 X = 1:.1:10;
 Y1 = sin(X); Y2 = cos(X);
 plot(X,Y1); hold on; plot(X,Y2,'-r');
 [x y k] = ginput(n)
```

then after you click n times somewhere in the plot, you will get an output of the X and Y coordinates of where you clicked in the column vectors x, y and k will give you which mouse button was clicked at each of those locations.